# how to connect two azure linux virtual machine together step by step

Tags: azure-web-app-service

i am trying to link two Microsoft Azure Linux virtual machines through ssh connections. When I tried with

```
 $ssh 10.0.0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect to your Linux VMs you need a public-private key pair (SSH keys) which can be done by following [this documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/mac-create-ssh-keys) to create your SSH keys if you haven't done so already. Once you have your SSH keys you can SSH to your VM using the IP address or DNS name of your VM. You can follow the steps in this [Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-keys-detailed) to connect your Linux VMs.

Alternatively, you can try using [Virtual Network Peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-portal) via the Azure portal. You can connect virtual networks to each other with virtual network peering. Once virtual networks are peered, resources (including VMs) in both virtual networks can communicate with each other, with the same latency and bandwidth as if the resources were in the same virtual network.